Mouse pointer does not appear during Prt Src video recording even when Shown Pointer is selected in Ubuntu 22.04
I am aware of this question and its answer. However, its answer does not work. Is there a way to show the mouse pointer during a screencast video recording for Ubuntu 22.04 ?
$ uname -a
Linux Machine1 6.5.0-35-generic #35~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue May  7 09:00:52 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 42.9

$ gnome-screenshot --version
gnome-screenshot 41.0

Ubuntu Desktop comes installed with a slightly modified version of the GNOME Desktop Environment. Desktop recording is done via GNOME screencast.

It could simply be that the unnamed recording program you are using does not support this feature.

@David what is a unamed recording program? I had thought that GNOME screencast that comes with Ubuntu 22.04 is in use. Is this not the case?

Please edit the question and add this info, not as a comment. Yes till this comment there was no way to know what app or feature you were using for the recording.

@David I have added my comment to my question per your request.

when using the screenshot tool, there are 6 icons visible - Selection Screen Window Screenshot/Screencast capture buttonand thenShow Poimter`. which is a toggle. Click to set it on then take you screenshot.

@graham My mouse pointer does not show during screencast even though the Show Pointer icon was toggled.

When using the screenshot tool Print Scrn, there are 6 icons visible - Selection Screen Window Screenshot/Screencast capture button and then Show Pointer which is a toggle.
Click to set it on then take your screencast with it set on.
Turn it off again next time you use the tool if you don't require it.
